# How do I animate flipping an image into another image?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

How do I flip the images like the below link?

[flipping-cards-3d-wordpress](http://codecanyon.net/item/flipping-cards-3d-wordpress/full_screen_preview/4135044)

I want it to be done in certain time intervals. Is it possible to do it by using css3 only?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Among all the tutorials about CSS3 flipping cards, which one was the more understandable for you? What have you tried? Mind to share some code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS3 provides [`animate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and you can find here [some nice intro](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) on how to use this feature.

Here's an example of mine that uses two classes `flipH` and `flipV`, that applied to a parent element will know what to do with the child `card` element.
See thoroughly the CSS to properly setup your backfaces and get a clue of the uses of hover (if needed)
 transitions but mostly - the alternating animations:

```css
/* ::: HOLDER, CARD, FACES */
.holder {
  display:     inline-block;
  width:       64px;
  height:      64px;
  perspective: 700px;
}
.card, .front, .back{
  position:   absolute;
  height:     inherit;
  width:      inherit;
  transition: all .7s;
  transform-style:     preserve-3d;
  backface-visibility: visible;
}

/* ::: FACES */
.front{background: tomato;}
.back{background:  slategray;}

/* ::: SETUP FACES */
.flipH .back{transform: rotateY(-180deg);}
.flipV .back{transform: rotateX(180deg);}

/* ::: HOVER EFFECTS (Remove Automated for this to work) */
.flipH:hover .card{ transform: rotateY(180deg); }
.flipV:hover .card{ transform: rotateX(-180deg); }

/* ::: AUTOMATED EFFECTS */
.flipH .card{
  animation: flipH 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
.flipV .card{
  animation: flipV 2s 0s infinite alternate ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipH {
  0% { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
}
@keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes flipV {
  0% { transform: rotateX(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotateX(-180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">A</div>
    <div class="back">B</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipV">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front">A</div>
    <div class="back">B</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="holder flipH">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="front"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/1ZIkv.jpg?s=64&g=1"></div>
    <div class="back"><img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/776st.jpg?s=64&g=1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What I wanted was to happen the animation like in a loop, first A flips, next B flips, next C flips and then A again, B next so on. Is this possible ?

Comment: @mars that seems to be another question... Yes it's possible. Have you Goog "how to pause a CSS3 animation" ?

Comment: @BinkyNichols sorry it was a leftover error. You had to set `backface-visibility` to `visible`. - Fixed-